# Flatten inherited members in Visual Studio's Watch window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

Is there some way to make the Watch window display all inherited properties and fields in one long flat list, rather than hidden behind a nested "base" node?

I'm debugging some C# code that makes massive use of inheritance - some of the properties I want to watch are behind three levels of "base" in the Watch window. This would be more or less bearable if I just wanted to examine a single such object, but I'm actually looking at a tree of them...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/02/19/flattening-class-hierarchies-when-debugging-c.aspx

**UPDATE:** I wrote a commercial tool called [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com) that solves this problem. The idea is that if you're interested in a property of the base class, you can "Star" that property, which causes the property to appear at the top of members list, and also in the text of its parent.

So for example, in the following scenario, I had to expand two base nodes to get to see the properties I wanted, "Important" and "Interesting":
[image: No Stars]

But once I star these properties, they will always appear at the top, even when viewing variables of the Derived type, so I'll see:

[image: After adding stars]

These [stars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvAsZe8xetM) are persisted and will be shown whenever you view a an object of that type in the DataTip or QuickWatch window from that moment on, so the next time you a variable of that type, you won't need to expand those "base" nodes. And because starred values appear as the parent node's text, if you're looking at a tree datastructure of these heavily nested objects (as you stated you were), you will be able to see these properties without even expanding the nodes at all.

**FULL DISCLOSURE**: I'm the co-author of the tool I've described here.

Comment: a) Does this still exist? (your site is down)  b) Does it work on all classes (native .Net framework classes)?

Comment: @tbone a) Yes, the product was re-branded under the name [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com), updated my answer  b) Yes it does!

Comment: Have you A/B tested pricing?  I'd love to have this, but shelling out $70 is a pretty large psychological block, even if economically illogical.

Answer (score 4):

Not as such.  You see, it is a feature!  The ability to see where a property comes from is important most of the time.

I understand your pain though.  There are some work arounds.  First, you can just put the ***object.property*** in the watch window.  This will just display the property you are looking for.  It is great for digging into a specific property but not so much for getting all the others.

You can also try ***(BaseClass)object***.  This will cast it to the base object that contains the property (properties?) you are looking for.  Again it is great for looking a a specific subset of properties but completly hides all the others.

Good luck and good hunting.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately neither of those ideas can help me view objects deep inside the tree :(

Comment: If you are talking about a private member of a DEEP class, you *should* be able to use the cast.  As I do not know your code, you might be correct in that you have to drill.  If that is the case, you just might be up the creek as they say.

Comment: Being able to see where the member comes from is certainly an important feature, but forcing you to navigate the inheritance chain instead of just displaying a flat structure with the source class for each member is a bug. >:(