# Flatten inherited members in Visual Studio's Watch window in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

This question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281128/flatten-inherited-members-in-visual-studios-watch-window), except that I'm debugging a C++ application. For the original question, a C# debugger has this functionality out-of-the-box now. Also, [third-party tools](http://www.oz-code.com/) for it exist.

Is there a way to achieve the same for C++? I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015.

EDIT 1
The classes in question are subject to change which limits use of Visual Studio's native Debugger Visualizers (natvis) feature. As far as I understand the custom visualizer will have to be modified every time the debugged class is changed, so that's not an option, regretfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not find the third party tool or extension tool for VC++ directly in VS IDE, but I know that we could create custom view for VC++:

Reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx

It would be a workaround if you want to custom the debug watch view.

Update:

No other extension tool, but I help you submit a feature request to the product team here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18574198-flatten-inherited-members-in-visual-studio-s-watch

If possible, you could add your comment and vote it.

Comment: It would be if the questionable classes were somewhat "final", so to speak. If I have to redo visualizer every time I change every debugged class, I'm better off expanding base class entries or even manually logging their data to file.

Comment: @S. Kalabukha, I also understand your requirements, I help you submitted a feature request to the product team, if possible, you could also vote it. Have a nice day.

Comment: And I did, thank you. Also, I accidentally clicked on the "flag as inappropriate" link :(. There must be a way to undo this. This might be another suggestion...

Comment: Thanks for your response, S. Kalabukha. I will also research this issue and discuss with other members, if I got any better workaround, I will share it here. Of course, I will help you follow up that feature request, maybe the product team could share us some useful information there.

Comment: As a workaround, I'm using the suggested feature for now. However, I noticed that I'm striving to alter my code design to limit the affected classes and structures, which leads to more poor experience debugging the ones that aren't subject to visualizing, unless I cover them all with natvis. I really hope the situation will improve, maybe in some future versions of VS.